# Java program for generation of 16 digit number to orginal number

Tags: java

I have a requirement like i am entering 4 digit number 1101 then i need to generate 16 digit number(1234567891234567). when enter the generated 16 digit number then i need to display the entered number 1101. how to do it in java

Comment: How about using a map?

Comment: `long output = (input < 10000 ? input + 1234567890120000L : input % 10000)`

Comment: or even simpler: `long output = 1234567891234567L - input`

Comment: Should the 16 digit number just be a random 16 digit number, or is there a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a Bidirectinal Map

```
class BiDirMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K, V>{

    Map<V,K> reversedMap = new HashMap<V,K>();

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        reversedMap.put(value, key);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    public K getKeyFromValue(V value){
        return reversedMap.get(value);
    }
}
```

and the **use it like:**

```
Map<Long, Long> myFoo = new BiDirMap<Long, Long>();
```

add elements like:

```
myFoo.put(1111, getNumberFor(1111));
myFoo.put(122, getNumberFor(122));
```

and find by the value like:

```
myFoo.getKeyFromValue(1234567891234567);
```

note that 3rd party libs like Guava will do that too

Comment: Thanks!!! it's working

Comment: Hi , there is no getNumberFor() method available in the class.Kindly update

Comment: ja... that is a method that is giving back a long calculated from the number 1111

Comment: Ok understood.. Thanks for your commnet